# Controlling Display Position And Appearance Of Item In List View

Tags: c#

I am developing an application where i will need to print the contents of a listview taken from a database. I have successfully displayed the listview,but i need to add an aggregate grouping of the total amount paid in the report and view it.I have done this(from my query..but i need this data to be under the "LAST TWO" columns of the listview and not the first two.In addition, i also want this items to be centered, and will want the font to be bold.How can i achieve this. Below is my code so far:

```
           //setting up command 
            OdbcCommand commandSql = new OdbcCommand("SELECT stateid,surname,firstname,amount FROM scheduledpayment", _connection);
            OdbcDataReader odr = commandSql.ExecuteReader();
            while (odr.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(odr["stateid"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(odr["surname"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(odr["firstname"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(odr["amount"].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
             OdbcCommand commandSql2 = new OdbcCommand("SELECT sum(amount) amount FROM scheduledpayment", _connection);
            OdbcDataReader odr2 = commandSql2.ExecuteReader();
            while (odr2.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("Total");
                item3.SubItems.Add(odr2["amount"].ToString());

                listView1.Items.Add(item3);
            }
```

And The OutPut Is:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------  


              200502317 BLACK   GRAY    15000
              200604572 BROWN   PURPLE  45000
              Total     789900
```

How can i make the output of the listview look like:

```
              200502317 BLACK   GRAY    15000
              200604572 BROWN   PURPLE  45000
                                Total  789900
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("");
item3.SubItems.Add("");
item3.SubItems.Add("Total");
item3.SubItems.Add(odr2["amount"].ToString());
listView1.Items.Add(item3);
```

Comment: Thanks..it works...any idea on how to align the items to either right/left and make font display bold?

Comment: @ewom2468: for every column in listview you can decide alignment (it's a property). To use a different font I think (but I'm not sure) you have to manually manage redraw...

Comment: @ewom2468: if you're using WinForms, in your ListView you declared four columns; well, open properties for the fourth one and there you'll find a property you can set to make your text right-aligned

Comment: I did...it only changes the alignment of the header text...not the items texts' alignment